# Log Out Facebook User When Authenticated With Firebase Auth

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, fbsdk

I have the following code that authenticates a user with Facebook and then with Firebase:

```
func authenticateWithFacebook() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: self) { (user, error) in // Signs up user with Facebook
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if (user!.isCancelled) { // User cancels sign up
            print("User Cancelled")
        } else {
            self.authenticateFacebookUserWithFirebase(credential: FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString))
        }
    }
}

func authenticateFacebookUserWithFirebase(credential: AuthCredential) {
    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Success")
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected. Once the user is authenticated with Firebase, what do I do with the Facebook user that has been "created" in the app? Do I need to keep track of the `currentAccessToken` and alert Firebase auth when the token expires? If not, do I just leave the code as is or should I log the Facebook user out of my app using the FBSDK? I just don't want a Facebook token floating around in my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user is not logged in to Firebase with Facebook as such. Your app does not get the user's facebook email and password credentials in order to log them into your app's Firebase. Instead it gets the access token for that user and then that token is used to authenticate the user with Firebase. Therefore you cannot log out your user from Facebook but what you can do is invalidate the access token.

Comment: So, do I just leave the Facebook user logged in through the Facebook SDK? In that case, what happens to the Facebook user when I log-out of Firebase auth?

Comment: Seperate two things: facebook login and access token. Your app only deals with the latter. So to answer your initial question directly, there is no facebook user for you to hold on and you cannot log the user out of facebook.

Comment: I think my original question was misleading. Please take a look at the revised question!

Comment: Oh man you are going a little bit ocd over this. When the user is signed up via facebook, firebase will use the token(to replace email/password) and create a new user-not facebook user, just user. Firebase Auth will know when it's expired as i am sure you are going to need current user in a few places in your app so nothing for you to do. If that's the case the user will not be able to be logged in with an expired token. Seriously, you are overthinking this, set it up and forget about it.

Comment: This helps a lot! I wasn't sure exactly how Firebase Auth handled the Facebook user. So when I log out of Firebase, it will handle invalidating the Facebook accessToken and I never need to call logOut on the FBSDK side?

Comment: Not sure if it invalidates it or just deletes it. The is no logOut for the FBSDK, look at the documentation. If you want to allow a user an FB authenticated user to log out from your Firebase all you have to do is call the logOut from Firebase.

Comment: Awesome, got it!